# Cannot restore appication when I minimize it

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have written a C# Desktop Application and when I have it waiting for a specific event (in a loop like as follows...

```
while (tf.Exists)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
}
```

I can inteact with my application and minimize it, but I cannot get it to restore.
Sometimes I get it to restore by clicking furiously with my mouse buttons while mumbling curses under my breath, but for the most part it will not restore.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in my loop?

Thanks ,

Greg

Comment: Why are you using DoEvents?  There are better ways to structure your code so it doesn't have to do this?  Might want to add more code.

Comment: You are making the UI thread sleep, and trying to work around the fact that you should never ever choose to do this by using `DoEvents`. Once you go down that rabbit hole, various things will invariably start going wrong. Choose a more appropriate way to wait for the event.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to repro without knowing how this code got started.  You never want to do it this way anyway, it allows the user to close your main window.  Now your loop is still running but without a user interface.

Use a Timer instead.  Perform the check in a handler for its Tick event.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than polling and calling `DoEvents`, which is seldom an effective approach, arrange for the event of interest to send you a message or fire an event.